# Can Intelligencia.UrlRewriter be made to work in IIS7?

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

We've inherited an application that uses the Intelligencia.UrlRewriter module. Our environment though is IIS7. We've already set our site to run in the classic asp.net application pool (which aparantly works for a lot of these kinds of problems). However we're still not seeing the URLs in our app be rewritten.

Has anyone run into this?

Answer (score 21):

You need to define the config on the system.webServer element, like:

```
    <system.webServer>
         <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="UrlRewriter" 
   type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
```

You can keep both config. What you probably have now is:

```
<httpModules>
      <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />
        </httpModules>
```

Check the section "Migrating ASP.NET Applications to IIS 7.0 Integrated mod" on http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/243/aspnet-integration-with-iis7/

ps. I have been using it with no trouble at all, as long as that config is in.

**Update 1:** Also check http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx, particularly "Approach 3: Using an HttpModule to Perform Extension-Less URL Rewriting with IIS7", since the config I added has the extension-less config.

Comment: Freddy, I gave that a shot but it didn't work.  

I think IIS7 doesn't like the url(ex: gallery/view/1 ) being extensionless. Can regex fix this?

Here's current:
<if url="~/showItem/item/(\d+)(/)?(\?.+)?$"><rewrite to="~/itemViewers/Items.aspx?itemId=$1" processing="stop" /></if>

Comment: hmm, I haven't used that style of config, mine looks like this:     <rewrite url="~/something/(.+)" to="~/whatever.aspx?code=$1" />

Comment: I don't have extra query parameters, and other stuff though. Anyway I would try it with a simple version first, to rule out anything with that config.

Comment: Is there a way that I can get it to work with "Classic" pipeline?

Comment: @Hiyasat the second snippet should make it work on the 'classic' pipeline, but just not for extension less paths. You need some extra configuration for it, but I don't have a link at hand.

Comment: Entries mentioned above under the system.webServer and httpModules worked for me for Integrated mode (IIS7.5)

Answer (score 1):

Yes I had the exact same problem with Intelligencia.UrlRewriter module, running under Win Vista & IIS7, however switching to the classic asp.net app pool did fix the problem. Are you running the app in a new virtual directory? That can sometimes mess with the root path to the application which could make a difference to the rules in the web.config

Answer (score 1):

I have spotted the same problem, after few tries I found out that changing asp mode to integrated pipeline helped.

Comment: I also have the situation where it works in Integrated mode but not in Classic mode.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add the following lines in the system.webServer section of your web.config file if you are using IIS7

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=”true”>
<add name=”UrlRewriter” type=”Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule” />
</modules>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration=”false” />
</system.webServer>
```

As in

http://frozengraphics.wordpress.com/2009/12/06/intelligencia-urlrewriter-and-iis7/