# URLRewriter for IIS 7 returns 404 Server Error

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I've implemented "**Approach 3: Using an HttpModule to Perform Extension-Less URL Rewriting with IIS7**" from here:
- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

That is based on **URLRewriter** module:
- http://urlrewriter.net/

It seems to work on my local environment but on production server (running IIS 7) it shows "**404 - File or directory not found**" page.

I've searched on Google and could not seem to find the solution.

In the end, we went back to IIS 6 and followed the instructions here which worked:
- http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support/installation/windows-server-2003

But someday we may have to upgrade to IIS 7 on a shared hosting environment and the same issue will appear again!

Comment: The hosting dude got it to work in IIS 7. All I got as to what he did was this "HTTP handlers requires wildcard mapping with different application pool to make it work in IIS 7". Hopefully this helps someone who could not find anything on Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hosting dude got it to work in IIS 7. The HTTP handlers requires wildcard mapping with different application pool to make it work in IIS 7. Hope this helps.

Make sure you have the following in **Web.Config**:

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  <handlers>
    <add name="wildcard" path="*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This is what I had to do in order to get non-existent URLs to map prpoerly.

Comment: A complete weg.config configuration can be found in this answer (for me this worked, solution above by Jason was not helpful in my case, asp.net 2.0 integrated, IIS 7.5): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615391/can-intelligencia-urlrewriter-be-made-to-work-in-iis7

Comment: Excellent! you save my day

Answer (score 0):

My colleague had the same problem and I check that he sets the app pool to use the Classic Pipeline instead of using the Integrated Pipeline which he should use and changing this to Integrated solved the problem. Maybe this could solve yours as well?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that my page p1 (has been rewritten, originally is p1.aspx) was mistakenly regarded as p1 directory.

I added <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" /> to the <system.webServer> in the web.config and it seems begin to work.

Answer (score 0):

**For IIS 7**

Copy the HttpModules definition in your web.config file from system.web to system.webServer

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
    </modules>
<system.webServer>
```

**Application Pools: Managed Pipiline Mode = Integrated**