# ManagedFusion Url Rewriting not working

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, .net-4.0, managedfusion

As per my other question [UrlRewriter.NET with .NET 4.0 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882329/urlrewriter-net-with-net-4-0-not-working) I was unable to get UrlRewriter.NET to work.

So now I have tried ManagedFusion. It works locally but does not work on the server BUT the errors are different and I sense that this might actually work and I have done something wrong in the configuration.

So my web.config settings are (condensed version)

```
<configuration>
   <configSections>
      <section name="managedFusion.rewriter" type="ManagedFusion.Rewriter.Configuration.ManagedFusionRewriterSectionGroup"/>
   </configSections>

   <managedFusion.rewriter xmlns="http://managedfusion.com/xsd/managedFusion/rewriter">
      <rules engine="Apache">
          <apache defaultFileName="ManagedFusion.Rewriter.txt" />
      </rules>
      <rewriter>
          <proxy useAsyncProxy="true" />
       </rewriter>
    </managedFusion.rewriter>
 <system.web>
     <identity impersonate="false" />

     <httpModules>
        <add name="RewriterModule" type="ManagedFusion.Rewriter.RewriterModule, ManagedFusion.Rewriter"/>
     </httpModules>

 </system.web>
<system.webServer>
   <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="RewriterModule" type="ManagedFusion.Rewriter.RewriterModule, ManagedFusion.Rewriter" />
   </modules>
   <handlers>
       <add name="RewriterProxyHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="RewriterProxy.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </handlers>
    <defaultDocument enabled="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

My ManagedFusion.Rewriter.txt is

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

#
# Campaign

RewriteRule ^/Campaign/List  /Campaign/List.aspx [NC]
```

Now this works perfectly fine on my local machine (Visual Studio 2010) but when I upload it I get a 404 that says it can't find /Campaign/List.aspx.

And on top of this it also goes to SSL, which I don't want as the SSL cert on that account is for a different subdomain and hence throws an SSL error.

Is there something I am doing wrong? It seems this time the URL module is handling all requests and this looks like I have configured it incorrectly somehow.

Additional Information

- Running IIS 7.0 - Integrated Pipeline
- .NET 4.0

Comment: I disagree with a random closing and down voting of this question. Yes it is 5 years old, the problem will still exist if you don't give the logging directory rights on the server as mentioned and it has a valid answer, which resolves the problem, even for other hosting providers. The Off-Topic flag on this question seems invalid as it can be reproduced and it was not due to a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this is actually a very common `GoDaddy` issue.  I am going to post an update to this answer after I review my notes and forums on the `CodePlex` site.

(by the way I am the primary developer of it)

You mind if we take this offline, we need to chat back and forth so I can understand your setup.  A quick way as explained in the `readme.txt` to trouble shoot problems is to turn on the logging.

```
RewriteLog /log/log.txt
RewriteLogLevel 9
```

The only problem with `GoDaddy` is that you need to create this log directory and give it write permissions, because if I remember right `GoDaddy` doesn't allow write permissions in the root.

Comment: Thanks. I have sent you an email.

Comment: U forgot mention that godaddy doesn't grant access to rewrite log by shared host...

Comment: Yes they do, you just can't have it in the root directory.

Comment: I can confirm that this is working for me as well, on GoDaddy 4GH Ultimate Windows hosting.  Note that you also have to create the log.txt in the log folder, or you will still get an error.